# Hidden Markov Model from Score Matrix

Tags: matrix, bioinformatics, hidden-markov-models

Im doing a course in bioinformatic.

Im trying to figure out how to model a Hidden Makrov Model (HMM) from a Position Specific Probability Matrix (PSPM).

Is there clear pattern how one should model it?
Can someone show me how to model it, with 3 or more states based on a PSPM.

I will supply a example of a PSPM, but feel free to use your own.

[image: PSPM] Example taken from MIT course.

Comment: It is not really clear what you want to do. You cold model each position as a state, with the probabilities given as emission probabilities. However, in such a model, the transition probabilities between the states would be "1". Thus, the state would not be hidden.

Do you want to identify occurences of this pattern/motif within a longer sequence? Then you should also have states for "outside motif" and suppose some emission probs for that state.

Comment: @cnettel , The question from the task is like this: "Design a HMM which models a DNA-sequence which can contain zero, one or several of TFBS
for TF A. Your answer should consist of a graphical representation of states and transitions which make up the HMM." I know how to model it as a normal markov chain, but not as a Hidden Markov Model.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not very clear, but maybe this will help.

For this models you can have as many positions as you want in principle.

Here therw is an example of what is possilbe to do in bioinformatics:

Let's imagine you have an alignment of DNA (we can call it "database"). You can build the model like this with [hmmer](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/hmmer/):

```
hmmbuild <hmm_profile> <alignment>
```

Then you can check the hmmer_profile which will contain all the transition probabilities for each position of the alignment and also the transition probabilities.

After that you can search new sequences against it for example. Now imagine you have a set of sequences ("queries") in a file and you want to map them against your "database", so you know which positions each query aligns better:

```
nhmmer -o <output_file> --dna <hmmer_profile> <sequences_file>
```

The output_file it returns the aligned sequences against the database.